# How to subtract date

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I'd like to get weekly subtracted date from reference date.

I tried following shell script

```
weeknumber = 10
Day = "2020/12/1"
    for ((j=0; j<$weeknumber; j++))
        calcDay="`date -d "$Day -$j weeks" +%Y-%m-%d`"
        echo $calcDay
    done
```

But it didn't return any day.
My desired result is following

```
2020/12/1
2020/11/25
2020/11/18
2020/11/11
.
.
.
.
```

Are there any good way to achieve this?

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you're using bash, then the syntax for your for loop is wrong. The right syntax is as below.

```
for <condition>;
do
<steps to execute>
done
```

You consider rewriting your code as below.

```
weeknumber=10
Day="2020/12/1"

for ((j=0; j<$weeknumber; j++));
do
calcDay="`date -d "$Day -$j weeks" +%Y-%m-%d`"
echo $calcDay
done
```

Note : If you want the dates to be formatted like 2020/12/1, then please consider mentioning the date format as ' **%Y/%m/%d** ' instead of ' **%Y-%m-%d** '

Comment: The OP tagged the question zsh, so this is probably be used. As a counting loop, this would be correct in zsh (and I think in bash too), except that the keyword `do` is missing. What **is** plainly wrong, is his assignment to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

No spaces when setting variables, and the syntax of the for loop should be respected.

```
weeknumber=10
Day="2020/12/1"
for ((j=0; j<$weeknumber; j++))
do
        calcDay="`date -d "$Day -$j weeks" +%Y-%m-%d`"
        echo $calcDay
done
```

giving

```
2020-12-01
2020-11-24
2020-11-17
2020-11-10
2020-11-03
2020-10-27
2020-10-20
2020-10-13
2020-10-06
2020-09-29
```

Comment: For consistency, I would drop the `$` from the numeric context completely, i.e. `for ((j=0; j<weeknumber; j++))`.

Comment: Please avoid useing backticks but use `$(date ... )`